# What is the 4th band in a 16 Bit 4 Band RGB TIFF?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, remote-sensing

I am using TIFF files in a project, all of which are plain RGB imagery. When imported into the software program that I use they are just automatically shown as being three bands, Red Green and Blue. However, when reviewing the metadata it shows that the TIFF files I am using are 4 band rasters. What data is contained in the fourth band and what is it used for?

Comment: It can be anything. You need to check with the source of your raster

Comment: I am the source of the raster. I flew a drone with an RGB camera, created an orthomosaic from the images, created a TIFF from the orthomosaic, and now I am left with a 4 band raster and no knowledge of what is held in the 4th band.

Comment: It's probably an alpha channel, but there's no way to tell with more details, i.e. how you created the ortho.